# SharePoint web applications and content database mismatch

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database

When I use Get-SPWebApplication command on sharepoint sever got 9 web applications names.When I use Get-SPContentDatabase got 15 content databases.How this mismatch happened??any idea???

Answer (score 2):

Some web application might have multiple Content Database, you can execute the same command again with Format Table

```
Get-SPContentDatabase | FT
```

This command will return the result in Table format, so that you can easily identify the web application by name

Answer (score 1):

This is because, one web application can connect to multiple content databases. So mismatch means, you have multiple databases in the web applications. You can check it via Central admin or run the below powershell.

```
Get-SPContentDatabase | select WebApplication, Name, CurrentSiteCount
```

Note: One content database only attach to single web application.